# Освобождение места удаленным файлом

Tags: администрирование

Возникла ситуация со следующими условиями:

- сервер с дистрибутивом ubuntu
- [проблема с atop](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=650222), из-за которой он записал в `/run/atop/atop.acct` четыре сотни мегабайт не знаю чего (я не имел дела с atop до этого и принял сервер уже с ним; насколько понимаю, он стоит из-за munin). Непосредственно файл был убит через `rm`.
- полностью забитый `/run` (df показывает 100%, du показывает значительно меньшее использование файлами, присутствующими в листинге)
- `/run/atop/atop.acct` удален через rm и не присутствует ни в физическом листинге файлов, ни в выводе `lsof` / `lsof +L1`
- `/run/atop.pid` существует, но пуст
- в выводе `ps aux` нет ничего, похожего на atop
- Запись новых файлов в `/run` невозможна по причине нехватки места
- Вывод `df -h`:

  ```
  Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  ...
  tmpfs           396M  396M     0 100% /run
  ...
  ```
- Вывод `du -ach /run/* | grep atop`:

  ```
  0       /run/atop/atop.acct
  0       /run/atop
  0       /run/atop.pid
  ```
- /run расположен на tmpfs, в другие места не смонтирован, на него симлинкуется /var/run:

  ```
  tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
  none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
  none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
  none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
  ```
- Вывод `lsof | head -1 && lsof | grep /run`:

  ```
  COMMAND     PID   TID       USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
  systemd-u   405             root    3u     unix 0xffff880036278000       0t0      12416 /run/udev/control
  dbus-daem  1661       messagebus    4u     unix 0xffff880036262940       0t0       8037 /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
  dbus-daem  1661       messagebus    8u     unix 0xffff8800369d8f00       0t0       1608 /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
  dbus-daem  1661       messagebus    9u     unix 0xffff880036263840       0t0      10865 /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
  systemd-l  1744             root   13r     FIFO               0,16       0t0      17443 /run/systemd/sessions/c1.ref
  systemd-l  1744             root   14r     FIFO               0,16       0t0  142943477 /run/systemd/sessions/20.ref
  systemd-l  1744             root   15r     FIFO               0,16       0t0  144221305 /run/systemd/sessions/23.ref
  zabbix_ag  1818           zabbix    3wW     REG               0,16         4      11548 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
  zabbix_ag  1830           zabbix    3w      REG               0,16         4      11548 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
  zabbix_ag  1831           zabbix    3w      REG               0,16         4      11548 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
  zabbix_ag  1832           zabbix    3w      REG               0,16         4      11548 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
  zabbix_ag  1836           zabbix    3w      REG               0,16         4      11548 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
  zabbix_ag  1837           zabbix    3w      REG               0,16         4      11548 /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
  cron       2049             root    3u      REG               0,16         5       8102 /run/crond.pid
  apache2    2305         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    2305         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    2305         www-data   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    2305         www-data   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    2701         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    2701         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    2701         www-data   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    2701         www-data   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    3238         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    3238         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    3238         www-data   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    3238         www-data   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    3278             root   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    3278             root   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    3278             root   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    3278             root   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  login      3319             root    6w     FIFO               0,16       0t0      17443 /run/systemd/sessions/c1.ref
  apache2    6811         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    6811         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    6811         www-data   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2    6811         www-data   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   11213         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   11213         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   14283         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   14283         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   14283         www-data   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   14283         www-data   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   17302         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   17302         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   17302         www-data   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   17302         www-data   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   17303         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   17303         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   17303         www-data   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   17303         www-data   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   19889         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   19889         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   19889         www-data   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   19889         www-data   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   21403         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   21403         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   21403         www-data   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   21403         www-data   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  sshd      21758             root    7w     FIFO               0,16       0t0  142943477 /run/systemd/sessions/20.ref
  apache2   22095         www-data   15w      REG               0,19         0  143142467 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-proctbl.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   22095         www-data   20w      REG               0,19         0  143142470 /run/lock/apache2/fcgid-pipe.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   22095         www-data   22w      REG               0,19         0  143142473 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.3278 (deleted)
  apache2   22095         www-data   23w      REG               0,19         0  143142474 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.3278 (deleted)
  sshd      22248             root    7w     FIFO               0,16       0t0  144221305 /run/systemd/sessions/23.ref
  ```

Как мне в такой ситуации очистить `/run`?

Comment: `lsof +r0 | grep deleted` чего-нить ищет?

Comment: @nobody из /run только локи апача, у всех size = 0

Comment: А можно ещё пожалуйста `df -h` и `du -ach /run/*` ? Не то, чтоб я не верил, просто так нагляднее для глаз)

Comment: @nobody обновил

Comment: А в остальном mount нет ничего подозрительного, эта же файловая система никуда больше не отражена, а то вдруг lsof с другими путями те же файлы показывает, а вы /run ищете

Comment: @Mike нет, ничего такого нет

Comment: А /var/run отдельный каталог, случайно не символическая ссылка на /run, вдруг программа открывала файл как /var/run/... и он все еще открыт. Собственно то что он еще открыт единственное объяснение почему место не освободилось. осталось найти что же это такое открыто ...

Comment: Хм, Вы грепаете по atop но мб проблема и не в нём вовсе? Попробуйте отсортировать по занимаемому месту: `du -ach /run/* | sort -h`

Comment: @Etki: разница в месте `du` и `df` - верный признак того, что есть файл(ы), который отмечен как удалёный, но чей дескриптор не освобождён. Выполните такую команду: `lsof | egrep 'DEL|dele'`. Условие grep'а, предложенное вам выше, не полное.

Comment: @МАН69К да его вообще в выводе lsof нет с любой фильтрацией.

Comment: @nobody, я же написал, что du выдает разумные значения, будто там почти ничего нет. `396K    total`

Comment: @Mike любые грепы по /run в этом случае все равно бы сматчили. Что именно открыто - я уже написал в вопросе, `/run/atop/atop.acct` или `/var/run/atop/atop.acct`.

Comment: @Etki: а можете куда-нибудь приложить `lsof | head -1 && lsof | grep /run`? На pastebin, к примеру, если слишком большой.

Comment: @МАН69К добавил в вопрос, но я же писал, что из удаленного там только следы апача

Comment: Может ребутнём? :)

Comment: @nobody не все серваки можно ребутать днем

Comment: @nobody: это слишком просто и не интересно :) Как читы в играх.

Comment: Была похожая ситуация, правда, atop был всё-таки виден через ps.  Решением было: 
1) rm /run/atop/atop.acct и
2) systemctl restart atop .

Comment: Думаю я опоздал к празднику ребута, но в следующий раз можно просто открывать /proc/<все пиды>/fd/ и смотреть "кто где когда".

Answer (score 1):

Проблема здесь в том что открытые файлы не удаляются, а продолжают существовать пока работает программа, их открывшая.

Убедиться в этом можно открыв на запись файл в одной консоли:

```
$ cat > /tmp/example.txt
```

И затем из другой консоли удалив этот файл:

```
$ ls /tmp/example.txt 
/tmp/example.txt
$ rm /tmp/example.txt
```

Затем можно проверить что файл продолжает существовать:

```
$ lsof -a +L1 /tmp
COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK     NODE NAME
cat       27223 sanmai    1w   REG   0,47       25     0 23585409 /tmp/example.txt (deleted)
```

Одним решением будет или закрыть, или перезапустить программу, держащую открытой удалённый файл. Но обычно программы поддерживают обработку [сигнала HUP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) именно для целей повторного открытия файлов логов и прочей реинициализации, `atop` не исключение (только лишь эта программа сама не перезапускается):

```
$ sudo pkill -HUP atop
```

Потому это будет более правильный способ решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая ситуация. 
Правда, `atop` был всё-таки виден через `ps`. 
Решением было:

```
rm /run/atop/atop.acct и 
systemctl restart atop
```